# Split array to string list when one of the items in the array is a string with commas

Tags: javascript, arrays, extjs, extjs5

To create a list in a dispayfield from an array, I use the following code that split the array items from the comma ',':

```
'fragrance_list': ["fragrance one" , "fragrance two", "fragrance seven"; 

 xtype: 'displayfield',
 name: 'fragrance_list',
 bind: '{record.fragrance_list}',
 renderer: function (value, field) {
 if (value && value.indexOf(',') > -1) {
    this.rndTpl = this.rndTpl || new Ext.XTemplate('<div style = "line-
 height: 150%;' +
        'margin-left: -25px; margin-top: -12px; padding-left: 5px; padding-
 right: 5px;">' +
        '<ul><li>{[values.fragrance_list.replace(/,/g, "<li/>")]}</li></ul>' 
         +
        '</div>');

   return this.rndTpl.apply({
      fragrance_list: value
   });

 } else {
    return '&nbsp' + value
 }
}
```

return something like:

```
. fragrance one
. fragrance two
. fragrance seven
```

The problem is when one of the array items, which may be in an indeterminate position of the array, has in its string one or more commas:

```
'fragrance_list': ["fragrance one" , "fragrance two", "fragrance A, n.º 5", "fragrance 7";
```

return

```
. fragrance one
. fragrance two
. fragrance A
. n.º 5
. fragrance 7
```

instead

```
. fragrance one
. fragrance two
. fragrance, n.º 5
. fragrance 7
```

Any ideas how to solve this?

Comment: If it's already stored in an array, why do you need to split it? Why not either iterate the array, or do `fragrance_list.join("<li/><li>")`?

Comment: Thanks user 184994 for help. Does not work in my case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure about the structure of your code, but if it's a long string you want to cut, you can add the quotes themselves to the `regex`:

```
 '<ul><li>{[values.fragrance_list.replace(/" {0,}, {0,}"/g, "<li/>")]}</li></ul>'
```

So the `regex` will match:

- single qute, (the **/"** part).
- zero spaces or more (the **' {0,}'** part).
- single comma (the **','** part).
- zero spaces or more (the **' {0,}'** part).
- single qute, (the **"/** part).

But, if you trying to build a list by values in an array (even if it's an array with one element) then the right way is to do it with a `map` function:

```
arrOfData.map( function(dataUnit){
    renderString += "<li>" + dataUnit + "</li>";
});
```

Or in `es6` syntax

```
arrOfData.map( dataUnit => renderString += `<li>${dataUnit}</li>`);
```

Comment: Thanks Elad. I'm trying to implement your solution. For some reason (I still can not understand) it is not doing the split of the items. All data is displayed in a single string

Comment: @josei If you want to split the string to array- you need to use the same `regex` but with the split function, like so:
`let arr = stringToSplit.split(/" {0,}, {0,}"/g);`

Answer (score 0):

```
>var frag= (fragrance_list.indexOf(' "," ') > -1)?fragrance_list.split('","'):fragrance_list;
```

*for first& last:*

```
 firstfrag=frag[0].split(' " ')[1];
 lastfrag=frag[frag.length-1].split(' " ')[0];
```

Comment: what is the problem .you can use escape character in case this(' " ," ') doesn't work? this is tested answer. thanks for letting me know.I will look for an alternate solution.

Comment: Thanks shubham1js. My goal is to display a list in a field. For this, what I'm doing is split the array by is items, in this case by the comma, and then create a list (<li />) from the obtained items. For this, I have to use an Xtemplate of Extjs. That is, any solution has to go through an XTemplate. Your solution is very interesting, but I could not adapt it in an XTemplate.

Comment: so basically, you are dealing with <TPL> in Xtemplate .let me check for this type of solution in my work.